# Cannot Inflate View While in ActivityGroup

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, spinner, activitygroup

I am using an ActivityGroup to open up Activity 2 from within Activity1, which lives under a TabHost. So I have a group of Tabs and Activity 1 is part of those, but when I click a button inside Activity 1 I want Activity 2 to open but still be under the tabs. This works fine using the following code:

```
    public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView(); 
    this.setContentView(view);
}
```

However, within Activity 2 I have a few spinners that inflate custom windows and call for using a SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
    @Override
    public View newDropDownView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    super.newDropDownView(context, cursor, parent);
    View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.custom_spinner_row, null);
    int labColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("lab");
    String getLab = cursor.getString(labColumn);
    TextView lab = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.CustomSpinnerTitle);
    lab.setText(getLab);        
    return view;
    }
```

I am getting this error:

```
 09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@40588a90 is not valid; is your activity running?
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:527)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:260)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-21 02:33:16.644: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1453):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The reason I am getting this error is because Activity 2 is not actually running because I replaced the contentView of Activity 1 with 2 in order to display it under the tabs. But I don't know any other way to do that. Is there a way to run Activity 2 under my tabs by in the same way actually run the activity rather than just replacing the contentView of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ActivityGroup that deals with `View`, so when you are using ActivityGroup you cannot directly `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);`. In that case you have to inflate your XML into View.

So, replace `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml)` by

```
View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(getParent()).inflate(R.layout.your_xml, null);
setContentView(contentView);
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: getParent() does not work. The context is not bad, but the activity is not actually started. I opened the activity by setting it to a view and then running that view inside of my first activities setContentView(). I had to do it this way in order to keep both activities under my tabs.

Comment: can you show the full code of Activity in which you are getting the error. And the error shows that you are using bad context here.

Comment: I updated the error code. The activity code is far too long to post the entire thing. But I know the error is due to how I am starting the activity because if I start is the regular way using an intent and startactivity, it works just fine. Right now I am just replacing the view of Activity 1 so that I can run Activity 2 under my tabs.